# Use the string of characters from a cell in a dataframe to create a vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

```
>titletool<-read.csv("TotalCSVData.csv",header=FALSE,sep=",")

> class(titletool)
[1] "data.frame"

>titletool[1,1]
[1] Experiment name : CONTROL DB AD_1

>t<-titletool[1,1]

>t
[1] Experiment name : CONTROL DB AD_1

>class(t)
[1] "character"
```

now i want to create an object (vector) with the name "Experiment name : CONTROL DB AD_1" , or even better if possible CONTROL DB AD_1

Thank you

Comment: What are the contents of the vector? What do you mean that the vector has that "name"? (A vector can have multiple names, one for each value).

Answer (score 1):

Use `assign`:

```
varname <- "Experiment name : CONTROL DB AD_1"

assign(varname, 3.14158)
get("Experiment name : CONTROL DB AD_1")
[1] 3.14158
```

And you can use a regular expression and `sub` or `gsub` to remove some text from a string:

```
cleanVarname <- sub("Experiment name : ", "", varname)
assign(cleanVarname, 42)
get("CONTROL DB AD_1")
[1] 42
```

---

But let me warn you this is an unusual thing to do.

**Here be dragons.**

Comment: Hello,Thank you for your answer Andrie, what i am trying to do is to do it without having to type "Experiment name : CONTROL DB AD_1"
i have 30  csv files containing data that i want to put in a easy to use format. All the info is already in the csv files, so i want to use what is in there so i don't have to go though each file to check wich sample it is. I will probably have more of these csv to analyse later, i might save quite a bit of time this way (i hope)

Comment: That's a really bad idea. Just don't do it that way. Use a named list instead. Create a list of data.frames by using `read.csv()` inside `lapply()`. R has great tools for working with lists.

Comment: @Andrie, I'm trying to be a mind-reader and [slay dragons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11530036/1270695) at the same time. I *think* that the OP might have multiple "experiments" in each CSV file, otherwise I don't know why the CSV name would be different from the experiment name.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a bunch of CSV files, each with multiple experiments in them, named in the pattern "Experiment ...". You now want to read each of these "experiments" into R in an efficient way.

Here's a not-so-pretty (but not-so-ugly either) function that might get you started in the right direction.

What the function basically does is read in the CSV, identify the line numbers where each new experiment starts, grabs the names of the experiments, then does a loop to fill in a list with the separate data frames. It doesn't really bother making "R-friendly" names though, and I've decided to leave the output in a list, because as Andrie pointed out, "R has great tools for working with lists."

```
read.funkyfile = function(funkyfile, expression, ...) {
  temp = readLines(funkyfile)
  temp.loc = grep(expression, temp)
  temp.loc = c(temp.loc, length(temp)+1)
  temp.nam = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", 
                  grep(expression, temp, value=TRUE))
  temp.out = vector("list")

  for (i in 1:length(temp.nam)) {
    temp.out[[i]] = read.csv(textConnection(
                             temp[seq(from = temp.loc[i]+1,
                             to = temp.loc[i+1]-1)]),
                             ...)
    names(temp.out)[i] = temp.nam[i]
  }
  temp.out
}
```

Here is an example CSV file. Copy and paste it into a text editor and save it as "funkyfile1.csv" in the current working directory. (Or, read it in from Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2556524/testing/funkyfile1.csv)

```
"Experiment Name: Here Be",,
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
"Experiment Name: The Dragons",,
10,11,12
13,14,15
16,17,18
```

Here is a second CSV. Again, copy-paste and save it as "funkyfile2.csv" in your current working directory. (Or, read it in from Dropbox: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2556524/testing/funkyfile2.csv)

```
"Promises: I vow to",,
"H1","H2","H3"
19,20,21
22,23,24
25,26,27
"Promises: Slay the dragon",,
"H1","H2","H3"
28,29,30
31,32,33
34,35,36
```

Notice that `funkyfile1` has no column names, while `funkyfile2` does. That's what the `...` argument in the function is for: to specify `header=TRUE` or `header=FALSE`. Also the "expression" identifying each new set of data is "Promises" in `funkyfile2`.

Now, use the function:

```
read.funkyfile("funkyfile1.csv", "Experiment", header=FALSE)
# read.funkyfile("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2556524/testing/funkyfile1.csv",
#                "Experiment", header=FALSE) # Uncomment to load remotely
# $`Experiment Name Here Be`
# V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  4  5  6
# 3  7  8  9
# 
# $`Experiment Name The Dragons`
# V1 V2 V3
# 1 10 11 12
# 2 13 14 15
# 3 16 17 18

read.funkyfile("funkyfile2.csv", "Promises", header=TRUE)
# read.funkyfile("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2556524/testing/funkyfile2.csv",
#                "Experiment", header=TRUE) # Uncomment to load remotely
# $`Promises I vow to`
# H1 H2 H3
# 1 19 20 21
# 2 22 23 24
# 3 25 26 27
# 
# $`Promises Slay the dragon`
# H1 H2 H3
# 1 28 29 30
# 2 31 32 33
# 3 34 35 36
```

Go get those dragons.

## Update

If your data are all in the same format, you can use the `lapply` solution mentioned by Andrie along with this function. Just make a list of the CSVs that you want to load, as below. Note that the files all need to use the same "expression" and other arguments the way the function is currently written....

```
temp = list("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2556524/testing/funkyfile1.csv", 
            "http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2556524/testing/funkyfile3.csv")
lapply(temp, read.funkyfile, "Experiment", header=FALSE)
```