# Making multiple plots in R from one textfile

Tags: r, plot, text-files, batch-processing

I'm new to R and trying to generate a lot of graphs from one file, with headers between different data sets.
I have a tab-delimited plaintext file, formatted like this:

```
Header: Boston city data
Month    Data1    Data2    Data3
1        1.5      9.1342   8.1231
2        12.3     12.31    1.129
3        (etc...)  

Header: Chicago city data
Month    Data1    Data2    Data3
1        1.5      9.1342   8.1231
2        12.3     12.31    1.129
...
```

I would like to create a graph of month vs Data1, month vs Data2, and month vs Data2, for each city.

I know in python, I could iterate through each line, do something different if the line starts with 'Header', and then somehow process the numbers. I would like to simply do this:

```
for (data block starting with header) in inf:
    data = read.delim()
    barplot(data, main=header, ylab="Data1", xlab="Month")
    # repeat for Data2, Data3
```

but I'm not sure how to actually iterate through the file, or if I should just split up my file by city into lots of small files, then run through a list of small files to read.

Comment: I recently threw together [a function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11530036/1270695) to separate such a file into a list. You can then use `lapply` to generate all your plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a combination of `gsub`, `grep` and `strsplit`:

```
## get city name
nameSet <- function(x) {
    return(gsub(pattern="Header: (.*) city data", replacement="\\1", x=x))
}

## extract monthly numbers
singleSet <- function(x) {
    l <- lapply(x, function(y) {
        ## split single line by spaces
        s <- strsplit(y, "[[:space:]]+")
        ## turn characters into doubles
        return(as.double(s[[1]]))
    })
    ## turn list into a matrix
    m <- do.call(rbind, l)
    return(m) 
}

## read file
con <- file("data.txt", "r")
lines <- readLines(con)
close(con)

## determine header lines and calculate begin/end lines for each dataset
headerLines <- grep(pattern="^Header", x=lines)
beginLines <- headerLines+2
endLines <- c(headerLines[-1]-1, length(lines))

## layout plotting region
par(mfrow=c(length(beginLines), 3))

## loop through all datasets
for (i in seq(along=headerLines)) {
    city <- nameSet(lines[headerLines[i]])
    data <- singleSet(lines[beginLines[i]:endLines[i]])

    for (j in 2:ncol(data)) {
        barplot(data[,j], main=city, xlab="Month", ylab=paste("Data", j-1))
    }
}
par(mfrow=c(1, 1))
```

[image: barplots]

Comment: Thank you both so much! (sorry, not enough reputation to 1+...) Seeing sample code and some slick looking final graphs is really helpful. I will be using a combination of both.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *slightly* modified version of the function referred to in my comment.

```
read.funkyfile = function(funkyfile, expression, ...) {
  temp = readLines(funkyfile)
  temp.loc = grep(expression, temp)
  temp.loc = c(temp.loc, length(temp)+1)
  temp.nam = gsub("[[:punct:]][[:space:]]", "", 
                  grep(expression, temp, value=TRUE))
  temp.nam = gsub(expression, "", temp.nam)
  temp.out = vector("list")

  for (i in 1:length(temp.nam)) {
    temp.out[[i]] = read.table(textConnection(
      temp[seq(from = temp.loc[i]+1,
               to = temp.loc[i+1]-1)]),
                             ...)
    names(temp.out)[i] = temp.nam[i]
  }
  temp.out
}
```

Assuming your file is named "File.txt", load the function and read in the data like this. You can add any of the arguments to `read.table` that you need to:

```
temp = read.funkyfile("File.txt", "Header", header=TRUE, sep="\t")
```

Now, plot:

```
# to plot everything on one page (used for this example), uncomment the next line
# par(mfcol = c(length(temp), 1)) 
lapply(names(temp), function(x) barplot(as.matrix(temp[[x]][-1]), 
                                        beside=TRUE, main=x, 
                                        legend=TRUE))
# dev.off() or par(mfcol = c(1, 1)) if par was modified
```

Here's what your small sample data look like with `par(mfcol = c(length(temp), 1))`:

[image]

Comment: +1 for using `read.table` + `textConnection` instead of my ugly `strsplit`.